# How To Override CSS Styles in Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, css

This code is injecting div in my website, I want to turn the `display:block;` to `display:none;`. How do I override the styles?

```
  var template = document.getElementById("MDow-1");
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("style", "display: block !important; clear: both !important".replace(/\s/g, " ".repeat(parseInt(Math.random() * 29 + 1))));
  var shadow = div.attachShadow({mode: "closed"});
  shadow.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
  document.body.appendChild(div);
```

This CSS style does not work.

```
.SelectorName { 
display: none; 
}
```

Comment: This may help? https://css-tricks.com/encapsulating-style-and-structure-with-shadow-dom/

Comment: You have to remove !important from setAttribute and add it to .SelectorName

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I'm following your question, to change the display of the div you could use

```
div.style.display = "none"
```